# change colors in image objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a black and white image, I would like to change the black in blue color and the white in yellow color(for example) in objective-c.

How could I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use Core Image to do this.

```
UIImage *bwImage = ... // Get your image from somewhere
CGImageRef bwCGImage = bwImage.CGImage;
CIImage *bwCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:bwCGImage];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];

// Change the float value here to change the hue
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5] forKey: @"inputAngle"]; 

// input black and white image
[filter setValue:bwCIImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

// get output from filter
CIImage *hueImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:hueImage
                                 fromRect:[hueImage extent]];

UIImage *coloredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

See documentation for more info: [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand where do I set the colors I want to replace with ? (black by blue and white by yellow)

Comment: For actual colour replacement you need to use a different filter. `CIColorCube` is probably what you want. In the ColorCube you define how colours map to different colors. You can read about CIColorCube in the link in the answer.

Comment: I can't see any example of CIColorCube, Where could I find one please ?